# NSManagedObjectContext -save: crashes when using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a search bar and some filters in my app that create two predicates. One for the string in the search bar and one for the filter (`UISegmentedControl`).

When the predicates are used and I insert one object into the context and then call `-save:` the app crashes with:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  Can't use in/contains operator with collection 1379410732 (not a collection) with userInfo (null)
```

at the point of saving:
[image: point of crash (SIGABRT)]

This does not happen when the predicates are not used.
Can I somehow remove the predicates during the process of saving? I already tried it by getting the `NSFetchRequest`, but I cannot set it back to the controller then.

**Edit**

I also tried to add `self` as an observer on the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and then use `-mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` like one discussion on SO suggested. This didn't help either.

Comment: Perhaps show the predicates?

Comment: Thanks Martin, I just found the problem. The solution still has a confusing part, but the crash is fixed. And you were right, it was the predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem. It was quite easy, but the error message was so confusing that I didn't look at the right point.

The problem was that I was using `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"number CONTAINS[cd] %@", string]`.

So the predicate was using `CONTAINS` on a `NSNumber`. The confusing part is that the predicates are working when querying existing data from the database. I still don't understand this part, but it's working now with `==` comparator.